# intersection of two sets without using the intersection operator

Tags: python, set, list-comprehension, intersection

I'm following a online course. There is this task. Two sets T and S. Write a comprehension statement over S whose value is the intersection of S and T. Use a membership test in a filter at the end of the comprehension.
I was thinking in the line of { *something* for x in S for in T if x is T}.

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Answer (score 1):

Single loop (set comprehension) is enough.

```
>>> S = {1, 2, 3}
>>> T = {4, 3, 5, 1}
>>> {x for x in S if x in T}
set([1, 3])
```